# Display label in custom uitableview cell after button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a custom `tableViewCell` with three labels(let's call this "A").

When the button is pressed in another cell of the same tableView(as all the table view cells are different), I want to display one more label along with those three labels in "A".

Should I hide the fourth label and unhide it after button press? How could it be accomplished? Is there any other way to do this?

Also should I add that label in my nib file? Won't this add extra space to the cell when the table is loaded the first time?

Thanks

Comment: Is it worked for you....

Comment: It does work! But the size of the nib that is loaded in tableviewcell remains the same. I want it to reduce in size if the fourth label is hidden.

Comment: You need to manage this by using constraints

Comment: As the fourth label is in between second and third label, will setting constraints solve the issue? If yes, what sort of constraints are we talking about?

Comment: For managing constraints you need to take fixed width constraints & take outlet of constraints. Change the .constant when hidden

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in following way

- There should be a entity object which hold the flag for showing the
  fourth label or you can have a global flag.
- Add target action on the button on which you want to change labels.
- Whenever the button touched you should change the flag & reload that
  section
- The code for hinding & unhiding the label should in
  method`tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath`

  ```
  -(IBAction)ShowButtonTouchUpInside
  {
      NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
      NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];                                     
      [self reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
   }


  - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
           static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
           UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
           if (isShowFourtLable)
           {
             cell.fourthlabel.hidden =  NO;
           }else
           {
             cell.fourthlabel.hidden =  YES;
           }
  ```

  }

Comment: Thank you for your help! What's the code for hiding and unhiding?